# Google drive share email does not use name but email address

Tags: google-drive

When I send (Share...) a file from Google Drive to someone, in the email notification he gets it shows my email address, instead of my name (see screenshot).

So, I want the above, but get the below.

It works correctly on some other google account (that is: I send a share link from another google account I own, for another document)
On what setting does this depend?

[image]

Comment: When you say, "It works correctly on some other google account," do you mean when you share something from another Google account you own?

Comment: @freginold Yes. I'll edit the question.